# TabPane - Why can't I change the empty tabzone color?

Tags: java, css, javafx

I'm trying to change the grey area in this JavaFX project I'm working on. I can manage to change everything, but not the grey area on the TabPane side.

I'm not sure if say a CSS file has to be set in some certain order, or maybe I'm just missing something else here.

Here's my code:

```
#tabPane {
    -fx-background-color: #94C5E3;
    -fx-tab-min-height: 64;
    -fx-tab-max-height: 64;
    -fx-tab-min-width: 64;
    -fx-tab-min-width: 64;
    -fx-padding: 0 -1- -1 0
}
.tab .tab-label {
    -fx-background-color: transparent;
    -fx-alignment: CENTER;
    -fx-text-fill: #627796;
}

.tab{
    -fx-background-color: #b5e4f6;
    -fx-pref-width: 100;
    -fx-background-insets: 0.0;
    -fx-background-radius: 0.0;
    -fx-padding: 0 30 0 30;
}

.tab:selected
{
    -fx-background-color: #94C5E3;
    -fx-background-radius: 0;
    -fx-background-insets: 0;
    -fx-border-width: 1 0 1 0;
    -fx-border-height: 1 0 1 0;
    -fx-border-color: transparent;

}

.tab:focused
{
    -fx-background-color: #94C5E3;
    -fx-focus-color: transparent;

}

.tab-tabPane *.tab-header-area .tab-header-background {
    -fx-opacity: 0;
    -fx-background-color: #b5e4f6;
}

.tab-pane:left *.tab-header-area
{
    -fx-background-color: #94C5E3;
    -fx-background-insets: 0, 0 0 10;
    -fx-padding: 0.0em 0.0em 0.0em 0.0em;

}

.tab:selected .focus-indicator
{
    -fx-focus-color: transparent;
    -fx-border-color: transparent;

}
```

And here is what it looks like:
[image]

Comment: Try changing `.tab-tabPane *.tab-header-area .tab-header-background {` to `.tab-pane *.tab-header-area .tab-header-background {`.

Comment: Thank you so much!